# Adding git to the path on Windows breaks Make?

Tags: git, path, gnu-make

I installed Git for Windows (the portable version) and added `"C:/Program Files/Git/bin"` to my system path variable. When I did this it messed up my make that I have installed from Mingw-w64.

When I run the command to build my project (`make all`), I get this error:

```
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, echo compiling src/prototype-main.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
make: *** [make/targets.make:40: src/prototype-main.o] Error 2
```

When I remove it from my path variable, it works fine again. What's up with that? The only files in the `"Git/bin"` directory are:

```
bash.exe
git.exe
sh.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out that you need to put the `"cmd"` directory into the path, NOT the `"bin"` directory. This is definitely odd to me still, and I still have no idea why it messes up `make` if you put the `"bin"` directory on the path.

In the portable version of Git for Windows, there is a file called `"README.portable"`. It tells you to (alternatively to using the git-bash or git-cmd terminals) put the `"cmd"` directory on the path and use `git` directly.

If anybody knows why `make` breaks if the `"bin"` directory is on the path, I would still like to know what is going on.